# pandas skip a column

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I'm traversing a csv using pandas. The csv is uneven i.e. some extra columns (in some rows) with no headers. I'm getting this error

```
pandas.errors.ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 11 fields in line 8, saw 12
```

I read some solutions but some of them are skipping the whole line and other suggesting a manual tweaking. I can not afford both. 
I need a method that can remove the extra column keeping the rest of row.

Here's example of data

```
Country    Phone         Fax    
Germany 030-0074321    030-0076545
Mexico  (5) 555-4729   (5) 555-3745
Mexico  (5) 555-3932    NULL
67000   France         88.60.15.31      88.60.15.32
28023   Spain          (91) 555 22 82   (91) 555 91 99
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Could you please share an example of your data?

Comment: I've updated in the question itself. Please have a look.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have columns ['A','B','C','D','E'] and 4 rows such that dataframe df looks like:

```
Row   A B C D`E
1     1`1 1 1 5 
2     0 2 0 0 
3     2 4 1 2 2
4     5 4 5 4
```

Now if you want to remove the extra column 'E' values from rows 1 and 3 then you can simply make another list

```
features=df.columns
f=[]
for feature in features:
    if df[feature].notnull().all():
        f.append(feature)

df=df[f]
print df
```

Therefore output will now be:

```
Row   A B C D`
1     1`1 1 1  
2     0 2 0 0 
3     2 4 1 2 
4     5 4 5 4
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: without reading the csv, how would I know what columns I'm having?

Comment: for reading the csv into a dataframe use pandas command as follows:
import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_csv(pathtofile)
then perform above step

Comment: that's where the problem is. When I'm reading the csv using read_csv, it is throwing above mentioned error.

Answer (score 0):

if you know how many columns you having.

```
data = pd.read_csv('data.csv',usecols=[0,1,2,3])
```

;[0,1,2,3...]; is column which has content.
else you don't know.

```
#enviroment -- python2.7

import pandas
data = pandas.read_csv("file.csv")
names = list(data)
for name in names:
    if "Unnamed" in name:
        data.pop(name)
print "result"
print data
```

Comment: I don't know how many columns I'm having. It can differ. I can not afford to manually read csv, enter static number of columns everytime.